# Is it possible to block spammers based on country of origin?

Tags: support, spam

Do we know the country of origin of the recent spammers?

If yes, can all IP addresses from a single country be blocked for a few weeks to discourage these spammers from posting?

The usual flagging and downvoting has not been working effectively from what I can tell. So what else has been done in this regard? What have we learnt about these spammers?

Are [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/187039) aware of this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relevant country of origin for this wave is India.

I have to believe blocking India would cause a few problems here.

We're keeping an eye on this & trying a few things to slow them down. Best thing to do right now is just flag stuff (as rude / abusive) as soon as you see it.